# decommission web site url redirect to some another site in IIS

Tags: iis-7

Recently I deleted website completely from IIS. But website url point to home page. I would like to know where can i check and delete completely. server is configured siteminder.

Comment: Could you please share how you deleted a site from iis and which URL it is using before? and which home page it is pointing to. please share a screenshot of the page.try to clear the browser history and cache and restart iis server. also, try to run the failed request tracing to check what is going wrong. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Comment: I went IIS manager then right click on desired decomission site(https://orasusrapp.com) -->deploy and delete option and finally site was removed. After that I entered above url is point to home page(https://Mytools.com). This IIS server is production server, So I did not restart the server.

Comment: please check that is there any other site is using the same binding? or URL rewrite affect this? try to run the frt and check for more detail. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Comment: No other site using same binding.